# How to write to a file from a dictionary with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a certain format I want to follow. It goes like this.

1 aaa

2 bbb

3 ccc

etc

The key and value separated by a single space. I have the code to turn it into a dictionary however I don't know how to do the opposite. The code I have to write the contents of the file to a dictionary is.

```
    def readlines(self):
        self.user_list = {}
        for line in score_file:
            (key, val) = line.split()
            self.user_list[key] = val
```

I need to update said dictionary during the course of the program and then print the updated contents to the file in the same format it came in. I would prefer if the code used to do the opposite of the above code follows a similar format without needing to import any modules. The file is in .txt. Thanks for the help.

Comment: try this `for k, v in self.user_list.items():
    fw.write(k + ' ' + v + '\n')`

Comment: I'm pretty new to python. What does the "fw.write" do?

Comment: `fw` file open for writing `open('output.txt', 'w') as fw`

Comment: I've imported it as ```score_file = open('rating.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf-8')``` How would I that code with this type of import?

Comment: are you creating new file or trying update the same file

Comment: update it. It's a game. When you win you get points, which is the value represented in the dictionary. I need to update the dictionary and then paste the dictionary to the file in the mentioned format. In addition if the user puts a name that isn't already in the file, i need to update the dictionary with the new name and paste that to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you close your file every time you need it. So it won't be open all the time.

```
def write_to_file(self):
   # w for write mode
   score_file = open('rating.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
   to_write = ""
   # please rename self.user_list as it is not a list but a dictionary
   for key in self.user_list.keys():
       # value + space + key + new line
       to_write += self.user_list[key] + " " + key + "\n" 
   score_file.write(to_write)
   # if you don't need the file anymore, close it
   score_file.close()
```

Comment: It didn't work as intended, Instead of updating the list, it added the "JJ 300Nathan 500" to the end f the file. Which has the score updated but has the remains of before still there and itsnt spaced. How would I fix this. Thank you the help.

Comment: It added it because you opened the file in read+ mode. this mode will only append, not overwrite.

Comment: What mode should I use. I still need to be able to read it an write to it. Sorry for not getting it. I'm still new. Also how would I format it properly?

Comment: Also it is closed farther down. I just didn't want to post the whole thing.

Comment: If I use write+ the file is wiped before I can access any of the values.

Comment: I would open it, do sth (read it)  and close it. For writing new values, you will do the same.

Comment: Alright, and how would I format it properly now? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wait I figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can only write strings to files and not dictionaries. For doing this, you will have to convert the dictionary to string and then push it to a file.

```
import json

myDict = {1: 'value1',2:'value2'}

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(myDict))
```

Comment: It's possible to write the dictionary directly to a file without using the json module

Comment: How would I do it without the json module. I'm not able to use said module.

Comment: try using use pip install json @Botonian

Comment: I mean, I'm currently learning using the Jetbrains program, and I'm not able to use it. Thanks for the help though. :)

Comment: op wants the output file in same format as input file not json

Comment: @Justlearnedit Yes, Of course, you can just use str() method to convert dictionary to string and then push it to the file & as I said earlier, you cannot directly push dictionaries to a file in Python yet.

Comment: How would I get a dictionary to be represented like the example in my question without using json?

Comment: Please let me know the format of answer in your question, maybe I could help. @Botonian